# Move parts of file to other files and keep git history

Tags: git

I have a large file with complex history (many commits from many authors).

Refactoring it would suppose to split it in multiple small files, BUT, i need to keep history.

To fix the ideas, let's say I have a `main` file containing all my code :

```
function a() {}
function b() {}
function c() {}
function main() {
   a();
   b();
   c();
}
```

and I need to move the `a` and the `b` functions to `a` and `b` files respectively while keeping my `main` function in the `main` file -- WHILE keeping history in the three files.

I found some kind of solution [there](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190918-00/?p=102901), but nothing that actually works or is practical in a production environment.

Comment: What happened when you followed the method you linked to? Did the history not show up how you expected? Or did you dislike some side-effect of it?

Comment: @IMSoP way too complex and time consuming. I have multiple large files that I need to split in multiple sub files

Comment: I haven't read through carefully, but it looks to me like you could mostly automate Raymond's method: create the various result files, put them in a folder outside the repo, and then have a script to loop over creating a dummy branch for each one and merge them all together.

Comment: I would recommend to not attempt to retain this sort of history. As you're discovering, it can make simple changes complicated. You spend orders of magnitude more time changing the code than doing code archeology, it doesn't make sense to optimize for code archeology.

Comment: If you want to later review the history, look through the history of the original file.

Comment: I agree with @WilliamPursell. In the commit message where you do the split, perhaps add a sentence explaining which file and commit ID you split from.

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as "file history" in Git: the commits *are* the history, and that's all there is. Programs like `git log` and `git blame` attempt to conjure up a file history by reading the actual (commit) history; the extent to which they're successful lies somewhat in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 6):

Move the code as normal. Git can help you read the history.

Use `git blame -w -n -M -C -C -C`. I like to alias this as `archeology`.

- `-w` ignores trivial whitespace changes.
- `-n` shows the line number of the original commit.
- `-M` detects moved or copied lines within a file.
- `-C -C -C` detects lines moved or copied from other files in any commit.

Similarly, use `git log -w -M -C -C -C`.

You can also make the archeology easier by copying the code in one commit, and changing it in the next. Then when you're reading back through the blame history you'll hit a commit that says "split up file X".

Ultimately, you spend orders of magnitude more time changing the code than doing code archeology. It doesn't make sense to optimize your development process for code archeology. Instead, change the code as needed and use Git more effectively. And if, in the end, the archeology is a little more difficult that's fine; it's better than making development more difficult.

Sooner than you'd think, especially if you [embrace change as a normal part of development](https://www.refactoring.com/), nobody will care where the original lines came from.

Comment: Although it does not seem to be the priority of the OP, would your commands above make it easier to merge code when splitting up files? I ran out of time while performing a major code refactor, and I am not in the unfortunate position of merging new code into the refactored branch. Most of the renames took, so most of merges so far have not very challenging; however, there were some files that needed to be broken up. I still have more refactoring to do, so if your commands would help "guide" the merges when splitting up a file, that would be fantastic!

Comment: @Todd This would be better as a question with full details, reply with the link and I'll have a look. However, my advise is to try and split the refactoring up into smaller incremental refactors. For example, rename a file but don't change the contents and merge that. Split up one file and then merge that.